# How I can delete the result of this selection query in a single mysql command?

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates, freeradius

Table name radacct radacctid is the pk accountuniqueid is the almost unique string generated by subscribers at connection time.

This is the mysql query that ouputs duplicated entries I want delete the result in the same command y order to automate this process.

```
select *
from radacct
group by acctuniqueid
HAVING
(radacct.acctuniqueid > 1)
```

Comment: Do you want t delete whatever gets outputed in this query

Comment: Be careful what you wish for. If the query says acctuniqueid=100 do you want to delete EVERY row where acctuniqueid=100 **or do you want to KEEP just ONE ROW where acctuniqueid=100**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you meant `HAVING COUNT(acctuniqueid) > 1` in your `HAVING` clause. If you truly want to delete ALL duplicates (i.e. keeping NONE of the dupes):

```
DELETE FROM
    radacct
WHERE
    `acctuniqueid` IN (
        SELECT `acctuniqueid` FROM (
            SELECT `acctuniqueid`
            FROM radacct
            GROUP BY `acctuniqueid`
            HAVING COUNT(`acctuniqueid`) > 1
        ) x
    )
;
```

The intermediary `SELECT` is necessary for MySQL to ignore the same table reference within a direct sub-select.

Please be advised to perform a full table backup before the deletion.

Comment: Thank you works very well, that exceed my capacity in MySQL area.